# Replacing elements in html string

Tags: jquery

Problem: I am trying to replace elements of a certain class with an empty string.

What i've tried

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>Cell to keep</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='hide-report-item'>
        <td>Remove Me</td>
     <tr>
</table>

<script>
<!-- In my scenario data is actually a partial coming back from an ajax call) -->
function ParseData(data)
{
                var foo = $(data)[2];
                var hideItems = $(foo).find('.hide-report-item');

                hideItems.each(function () {
                    var test = $(this)[0];
                    data = data.replace(test.outerHTML, '');
                });
}
<!-- Ive also tried different variations of this -->
function ParseData(data)
{
                var foo = $(data).find('.hide-report-item').hide();
                var hideItems = $(foo).html();
}

<script>
```

Expected output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>Cell to keep</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the elements you want to remove, then .remove() them with jQuery

```
$(function() {
 $( ".hide-report-item" ).remove();
});
```

Comment: data comes in as a string. When i convert it using for example 

foo = $(data) 

foo is an array [0] <br /> [1] text [2] tablerow. Any kind of remove or hide and foo.html() returns an empty string

Comment: But that data still just ends up in the DOM right? Why can't it be manipulated with jQuery after load?

Comment: oh i see what youre saying. gimme a second to try it

Comment: No problem at all :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `remove()` method.

```
$('.classToRemove').remove();
```

No need to use `each()` or any other loop.  This will find all of those elements with that class in the DOM.

Comment: data comes in as a string. When i convert it using for example

foo = $(data)

foo is an array [0] <br /> [1] text [2] tablerow

any kind of remove or hide and foo.html() returns an empty string